# ElasticSearch query error: query malformed, no start_object

Tags: elasticsearch, elastalert

I was providing the below query to ElasticSearch:

```
{
    "bool": {
        "filter": [
            [
                "000TBT-E",
                "07N3P3-E",
                "BNTX",
                "PFE"
            ],
            {
                "terms": {
                    "query_uuid": [
                        "0284EFDB592041B7BEC9867C096FD881",
                        "051AA9969F3140BFABA50B2B195249CF",
                        "079EF8038042418EA3A219A62A09845A",
                        "0890230614E14DE59473C9A2ADA72FC9",
                        "0A8B26197C034154B516652E30100D4D",
                        "110D2E40E2E04DB6845D0CFC62FA537B",
                        "12529A8CB715483F98333818FCBD54C8",
                        "1379AD490F914C8893B68E41ACF115C0",
                        "137C1B522A37441884B566F914127836",
                        "13A0E9DCD4DE4350985802D1826252DF",
                        "FE4F0480A0D04B7FB67B3E9B8BC96496"
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

When this query was executed the threw the error:

```
'{"col":106,"line":1,"reason":"[_na] query malformed, must start with start_object","root_cause":[{"col":106,"line":1,"reason":"[_na] query malformed, must start with start_object","type":"parsing_exception"}],"type":"parsing_exception"}'
```

May I know what I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues in your query:

1. You need to put everything inside the `query` section
2. The first filter is not acting on any field

Here is a working query:

```
{
  "query": {                      <-- add this
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "terms": {              <-- add this
            "fieldname": [        <-- add this
              "000TBT-E",
              "07N3P3-E",
              "BNTX",
              "PFE"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "query_uuid": [
              "0284EFDB592041B7BEC9867C096FD881",
              "051AA9969F3140BFABA50B2B195249CF",
              "079EF8038042418EA3A219A62A09845A",
              "0890230614E14DE59473C9A2ADA72FC9",
              "0A8B26197C034154B516652E30100D4D",
              "110D2E40E2E04DB6845D0CFC62FA537B",
              "12529A8CB715483F98333818FCBD54C8",
              "1379AD490F914C8893B68E41ACF115C0",
              "137C1B522A37441884B566F914127836",
              "13A0E9DCD4DE4350985802D1826252DF",
              "FE4F0480A0D04B7FB67B3E9B8BC96496"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```